# I want to select multiple rows from JTable and get them on JTextArea to generate the bill

Tags: java, swing

```
public void bill() {
    int[] selectedRows = jTable2.getSelectedRows();

    // Initialize total amount
    double totalAmount = 0.0;

    // Use a StringBuilder to construct the entire bill content
    StringBuilder billContent = new StringBuilder();

    // Append "THE BILL" header only if there are selected rows and the header hasn't been added
    if (selectedRows.length > 0 && !headerAdded) {
        billContent.append("==================================\n");
        billContent.append("\t THE BILL \n");
        billContent.append("==================================\n");
        billContent.append("\t" + "Prod_name" + "\t" + "price" + "\n");

        // Update the flag after adding the header
        headerAdded = true;
    }

    // Append selected rows in the order they are selected
    for (int i : selectedRows) {
        String prodName = jTable2.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
        String priceStr = jTable2.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();

        // Extract numerical part of the price string
        String priceValue = extractNumericValue(priceStr);

        billContent.append("\t" + prodName + "\t" + priceValue + "\n");

        // Update the total amount
        totalAmount += Double.parseDouble(priceValue);
    }

    // Additional formatting and display the total amount only once
    if (selectedRows.length > 0 && !footerAdded) {
        // Append the footer to the StringBuilder
        billContent.append("\n");
        billContent.append("==================================\n");
        billContent.append("\t TOTAL: \t" + totalAmount + "\n");
        billContent.append("\t THANK YOU!!!! \n");

        // Set the content of the text area with the entire bill
        Area.setText(billContent.toString());

        // Update the total amount in jTextField1
        jTextField1.setText(String.valueOf(totalAmount));

        // Update the flag after adding the footer
        footerAdded = true;
    }
}
```

this is my code but it does not work as I want it to.

I am trying to get something like this

```
     THE BILL 
==================================
    Prod_name   price
    cake1   500
    capucino    500
    biscuit 100
    cafe    300

==================================
     TOTAL:     1400.0
     THANK YOU!!!!
```

In the code I provided, I am just getting the provided output once I select multiple rows at once and click the JButton to achieve it and what I want is to select rows one by one and if I click button I get the desired output as provided.

Comment: *to select rows one by one and if I click button...* - It would seem to me that you need two buttons. The first button ("Add to List") would be to add the selected row(s) to a List to allow you to select multiple items. Then you need a second button ("Generate Billk") to generate the bill once you are finished with the selections.